# Password can't be blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

My dashboard_user controller is:

```
class DashboardUsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_dashboard_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /dashboard_users
  # GET /dashboard_users.json
  def index
    @dashboard_users = DashboardUser.all
  end

  # GET /dashboard_users/1
  # GET /dashboard_users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /dashboard_users/new
  def new
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.new
  end

  # GET /dashboard_users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /dashboard_users
  # POST /dashboard_users.json
  def create
    @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.new(dashboard_user_params)
#@dashboard_user.password = @dashboard_user.encrypted_password
    respond_to do |format|
      if @dashboard_user.save
        format.html { flash[:notice] = 'User successfully Created.' and redirect_to action: "index"}
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /dashboard_users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /dashboard_users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @dashboard_user.update(dashboard_user_params)
        format.html { flash[:notice] = 'User successfully Edited.' and redirect_to action: "index"}
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /dashboard_users/1
  # DELETE /dashboard_users/1.json
  def destroy
    @dashboard_user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to dashboard_users_url, notice: 'User successfully Deleted.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_dashboard_user
      @dashboard_user = DashboardUser.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def dashboard_user_params
      params.require(:dashboard_user).permit(:user_id, :username, :normalized_user_name, :encrypted_password, :last_name, :first_name, :middle_name, :phone, :email, :seq_ques_id, :seq_ques_answer, :expire_password_ind, :expire_password_date, :deactivated_ind, :deactivated_date, :role_id, :created_by, :updated_by)
    end 
end
```

My dashboard_use model is

```
class DashboardUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable,:rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

#require 'digest'
  #before_save :encrypt_password
  #def encrypt_password
   # require 'digest'
    #self.password = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(self.password)
 # end



  attr_accessor :login
  validates :username, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50 ,message: 'Exceeds Maximum number of Characters.'}, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9]*\z/, message: "may only contain letters and numbers." }
  validates :encrypted_password, presence: {message: ' can''t be Blank!'}, length: {maximum: 50 , message: 'Exceeds Maximum number of Characters.'}
  validates :last_name, presence: {message: 'can''t be Blank!'}, length: {maximum: 50, message: 'Exceeds Maximum number of Characters.'}
  validates :first_name, presence: true, length: {maximum: 50, message: 'Exceeds Maximum number of Characters.'}
  validates :middle_name, length: {maximum: 50 ,message: 'Exceeds Maximum number of Characters.'}
  validates :phone, length: {maximum: 15 ,message: 'Exceeds Maximum number of Characters.'}
  validates :email, email_format: { message: "should be like : example@example.com" }
  validates :seq_ques_answer, presence: true, length: {maximum: 100,message: 'Exceeds Maximum number of Characters.'}

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions).where(["username = :value OR lower(email) = lower(:value)", { :value => login }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end
end
```

My form.html is:

```
<div class="form-group">
<%= simple_form_for(@dashboard_user) do |f| %>
   <% if @dashboard_user.errors.any? %>
    <ul class="alert alert-danger">
    <% for message_error in @dashboard_user.errors.full_messages %>
      <li> <%= message_error %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
  <table class="mytable">
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">
            <label for="UserName" >User Name</label>
        </td>
        <td class="col2">
            <%= f.text_field :username %>
        </td>
        <td class="col1">
            <label for="Password">Password</label>  
        </td>
        <td class="col2">
            <%= f.text_field :encrypted_password %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">
            <label for="LastName">Last Name</label>
        </td>
        <td class="col2">
            <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
        </td>
        <td class="col1">
            <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
        </td>
        <td class="col2">
            <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">
            <label for="MiddleName">Middle Name</label>
        </td>
        <td class="col2">
            <%= f.text_field :middle_name %>
        </td>
        <td class="col1">
            <label for="PhoneNumber">Phone Number</label>
        </td>
        <td class="col2">
            <%= f.phone_field :phone %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">
            <label for="EmailID">Email ID</label>
        </td>
        <td class="col2">
            <%= f.email_field :email %>
        </td>
        <td class="col1">
            <label for="SecretQuestion">Secret Question</label>
        </td>
        <td class="col2">
            <%= f.text_field :seq_ques_id %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">
            <label for="SecretAnswer">Answer</label>
        </td>
        <td class="col2">
            <%= f.text_field :seq_ques_answer %>
        </td>
        <td class="col1">
            <label for="Role">User Role</label>
        </td>
        <td class="col2">
            <select id=:ROLE_ID>
            <option>Select</option>
            <option value="1">Admin</option>
            <option value="2">User</option>
            </select><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
    <%= f.button :submit ,class: "btn btn-primary"%>

<% end %>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now my issue is getting Password can't be blank error when I create new user.

Comment: If you have multiple files to show then I recommend that you use [gist](http://gist.github.com) instead.

Comment: User is typing encrypted password in the field?

Comment: a gist would be more useful

Comment: No typing normal password

Comment: Do not put your code in an off-site repository. When link-rot sets in, your question will be meaningless to anyone searching for a similar question. Also, you're asking those who would like to help you, to chase down your code just to see what you're doing. They're working on their spare time, so make it easy for them to help you. And, you need to supply stripped down code that reproduces the problem. See "[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the problem. The field encrypted password is not for getting the password from the user or input end. Devise will encrypt your password and store it there. In your form.

remove the following line:

```
<%= f.text_field :encrypted_password %>
```

Now add two following lines:

```
<%= f.text_field :password %>
<%= f.text_field :password_confirmation %>
```

Make sure, your controller is permitting the required params also.

```
def dashboard_user_params
   params.require(:dashboard_user).permit(:user_id, :username, :normalized_user_name,
  :password, :password_confirmation, :last_name, :first_name, :middle_name, :phone, :email, :seq_ques_id, 
  :seq_ques_answer, :expire_password_ind, :expire_password_date, :deactivated_ind, 
  :deactivated_date, :role_id, :created_by, :updated_by)
end
```

> and you remove validations from your model for encrypted password.

Things should work now!

Answer (score 1):

First, you can't just enter encrypted password in the password field, so you need to remove `encrypted_password` field and add `password` and `password_confirmation` fields. **Remove**

```
<%= f.text_field :encrypted_password %>
```

and **add** these two fields

```
<%= f.password_field :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
```

Secondly, you need to remove validation for `encrypted_password` field, **Remove** this line from your model

```
validates :encrypted_password, presence: {message: ' can''t be Blank!'}, length: {maximum: 50 , message: 'Exceeds Maximum number of Characters.'}
```

Validation for password fields is already included in Devise's `validatable` module, so you don't need to add validation for that in your model

Hope this helps!

Comment: oh I forgot to mention that validation stuffs, that should be removed as well.! Thanks for that.