# Field cannot be blank even when I already add the value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, automation, build-automation

I'm new to Ruby, and currently trying to create a login step however somehow even after I fill in the value, it comes back with

```
      Request: {"headers":{},"timeout":60,"body":"{\n\t\"email\": \"johnsnow@gmail.com\",\n\"password\": \"AnotherJ0hnSnow\"\n}"}
      Response code: 400
      Response time: 78 ms
      Response body: {"message":{"email":"cannot be blank","password":"cannot be blank"}}
```

```
{"message":{"email":"cannot be blank","password":"cannot be blank"}}
```

Even when I already fill it with

```
    When client sends a POST request to "XXXX" with body: 
      """
      {
        "email": "johnsnow",
        "password": "AnotherJ0hnSnow"
      }
      """
```

Did I miss something?

Trying to log in by using the value that I input in the body

I already tried just using the token however somehow it still got 400 with an empty field

```
@access_token = ENV['API_TOKEN']
puts "access_token : #{@access_token}"

@headers = {
  'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
  'Accept' => 'application/json',
  'Authorization' => "Bearer #{@access_token}"
}
```

I also tried searching but somehow I didn't get what I'm looking for from the thread like: [Password can't be blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26751077/password-cant-be-blank) or
["Password can't be blank" Rails Rails 4.2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650999/password-cant-be-blank-rails-rails-4-2-4) by giving put, it shows up but still somehow it rejects in this step

Comment: Check you strong_params in your controller. Generally speaking, when presenting a problem you also need to show us your current code, otherwise this is just guessing. And please sanitize your logs - password should never appear in the logs unredacted, it's a serious security risk!

Comment: The fact that the request is coming in as a JSON string, and not JSON parameters, is likely a sign you're posting to the service incorrectly. Those parameters are missing. All you have is a `body` full of junk as far as Rails is concerned. How do you post this? What stack are you using? Maybe you need to enable JSON decoding.